# How to safely to a getAs operation on a spark dataframe row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
val df = Seq(("x", "y", 1),("x", "z", 2),("x", "a", 4), ("x", "a", 5), ("t", "y", 1), ("t", "y2", 6), ("t", "y3", 3), ("t", "y4", 5)).toDF("F1", "F2", "F3")


+---+---+---+
| F1| F2| F3|
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  1|
|  x|  z|  2|
|  x|  a|  4|
|  x|  a|  5|
|  t|  y|  1|
|  t| y2|  6|
|  t| y3|  3|
|  t| y4|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

I am performing the filter and value selection as follows:

```
df.filter($"F1" === "x" && $"F2"==="y").head.getInt(2)
```

The above works. But getting an exception on the below:

```
df.filter($"F1" === "x" && $"F2"==="y").head.getDouble(2)
```

Also, the following breaks when there are no records in the filtered dataframe:

```
df.filter($"F1" === "x" && $"F2"==="y1").head.getAs[Int]("F3")
```

So, how to safely execute `getAs[]()` and get the value? If the value
is an integer or double, I want to get it as double always, and if the
filtered dataframe is empty, then 0.0 should be returned.

Comment: Use with a Try( get(0).toString.toDouble).getOrElse(0). Or you could try explicit cast with asInstanceOf as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use dynamic API at all and head at all. Use strongly typed API and cast types explicitly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def get(df: DataFrame) = df.select($"F3".as[Double])
  .take(1).headOption.getOrElse(0.0)
```

Example usage:

```
get(df.filter($"F1" === "x" && $"F2"==="y"))
//  Double = 1.0

get(df.filter($"F1" === "x" && $"F2"==="y1"))
// Double = 0.0
```

Comment: can you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545470/how-to-convert-a-multiparameter-function-to-a-udf-in-spark   please